# Using a user-inputted string from one function to another in C

Tags: c, string, function, switch-statement

So... the main question is how I can use the string that the user entered in another function? I know it would be a lot easier to do it all in the main function but we are forced to use as many separate ones as possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You CANNOT return a locally declared string from a function. It ceases to exist when the function returns. Pass the `str` array to the function as an argument, then either use the string directly as an argument to the next function or return a pointer to it and pass that to the next function. e.g. `char str[25] = {0};` ceases to exist when the function returns (the function address space is gone).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin He's not returning a string, only the first character.

Comment: `void menuOptions(){;` why do you have a semi colon there?

Comment: But he has to be able to use the `word` entered by the use in another function. Your point is valid and if only a char is needed, it works.

Comment: You CAN do what he did, just return an int, the first char in the string. That is pushed onto the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from the comment, you most likely want to declare the `str` in a scope available to both functions:

```
int enterWord (char *str) {   
    ...
    scanf("%24s", str);
    ...
    return str[0];
}

int menuScan (char *str) {
    ...
}

int main (void) {

    char str[25] = {0};
    int someint;
    ...

    someint = menuScan (enterWord (str));

    return 0;
}
```

or

```
int main (void) {

    char str[25] = {0};
    int someint, someotherint;
    ...

    someint = enterWord (str);
    ...
    someotherint = menuScan (str);

    return 0;
}
```

You may want to employ a bit of additional error checking on the user input as well, e.g.:

```
int enterWord (char *str) {   

    printf ("Please enter a single word that is no more than 25 characters: ");

    if (scanf ("%24s", str))
        printf ("\nThanks! You entered:  %s", str);
    else
        return -1;

    return str[0];
}

...

int main (void) {

    char str[25] = {0};
    int someint, someotherint;
    ...

    if ((someint = enterWord (str)) = -1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "enterWord() error: input failure.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    ...
    someotherint = menuScan (str);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Remaining Issue With '\n' Left In Input Buffer**

Your remaining problems come from the fact that after you call `scanf`, you are leaving the `'\n'` (cause by pressing `[Enter]`) in the input buffer `stdin`. The next time your program calls `scanf` it takes the `'\n'` left in the input buffer as the user input. (if you check, you will find it is using the value `0xa` (or `10`) which is the value for `newline`)

You have two options. You can use a loop to empty `stdin`:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
```

You can also use the assignment suppression operator of `scanf` to read and discard the newline, e.g.:

```
scanf ("%24[^\n]%*c", str)
```

Where `%24[^\n]` read upto 24 chars (not including the `'\n'` into `str`) and `%*c` which reads and discards a single character (the `newline`). That way your input buffer is empty before the next user input.

Here is a short working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int enterWord (char *str);
void menuOptions ();
int menuScan (char *str);

int main (void) {

    char str[25] = {0};

    if (enterWord (str) == -1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "enterWord() error: input failure.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    do {
        menuOptions();
    } while (!menuScan (str));

    return 0;
}

int enterWord (char *str)
{   
    printf ("Please enter a single word that is no more than 25 characters: ");

    if (scanf ("%24[^\n]%*c", str))
        printf ("\nThanks! You entered:  %s", str);
    else
        return -1;

    return str[0];
}

void menuOptions ()
{
    printf("\n\n=========   MENU   =========\n\n");
    printf("Key     Function\n");
    printf("===     ========\n");
    printf(" C      Count the letters\n");
    printf(" V      Count the vowels\n");
    printf(" R      Reverse the word\n");
    printf(" P      Check if the word is a palindrome\n");
    printf(" W      Enter a new word\n");
    printf(" Z      Exit\n\n");
}

int menuScan (char *str)
{
    /* always initialize variables */
    char *p = str;
    char menuChoice = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int charcnt = 0;

    printf ("Please enter a character from the options above: ");
    if (!scanf ("%c%*c", &menuChoice)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "menuScan() error: input failure.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf ("\nYou entered: %c\n", menuChoice);

    c = menuChoice;  /* I don't like to type */

    /* validate input */
    if (c < 'A' || ('Z' < c && c < 'a') || 'z' < c) {
        fprintf (stderr, "menuChoice() error: input is not [a-z] or [A-Z]\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* convert to lowercase */
    if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') c += 32;

    switch (c) {
        case 'c': 
            for (; *p; p++) charcnt++;
            printf ("\n\nThere are '%d' letters in '%s'\n", charcnt, str);
            break;
        case 'z':
            return -1;
        default : printf ("(%c) invalid choice -> try again.\n", c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Compile**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -finline-functions -O3 -o bin/menuscan menuscan.c
```

**Example/Use**

```
$ ./bin/menuscan
Please enter a single word that is no more than 25 characters: 0123456789

Thanks! You entered:  0123456789

=========   MENU   =========

Key     Function
===     ========
 C      Count the letters
 V      Count the vowels
 R      Reverse the word
 P      Check if the word is a palindrome
 W      Enter a new word
 Z      Exit

Please enter a character from the options above: c

You entered: c


There are '10' letters in '0123456789'


=========   MENU   =========

Key     Function
===     ========
 C      Count the letters
 V      Count the vowels
 R      Reverse the word
 P      Check if the word is a palindrome
 W      Enter a new word
 Z      Exit

Please enter a character from the options above: z

You entered: z
```

Comment: I'm trying to grasp it. In your comment you skipped the function 'int menuScan', is that because it looks okay to you? I'm having a problem with it reading the case 'f' and can't really check whether what you said will help due to the errors.  EDIT%%  For the error checking, I'd rather lay off that at the moment until I figure out this basic thing first :P I will come back to it though, thanks!

Comment: Hold on, I skipped because I was only concerned about your main question `str` in `enterWord`.  Looking at `menuScan`, there is nothing inherently wrong. You can simply do `char *p = str; for (; *p; p++) i++;` for the length if you like.

Comment: @KyleSteward - you will need to fix the case statement. You can only have `'c'` or `'C'` per `case` statement, not both. Just set an individual `case` for each `char` you need to test.

Comment: When I run the code now I receive no errors. However, the program asks me to enter the word, then it prints the menu and 'menuScan' function and exits. It doesn't allow me to enter the character before it exits. Is that a 'return' issue?

Comment: I added a complete example. You were leaving the `'\n'` in the input buffer which was taken as the next user input. (that is why `scanf` functions give people so much trouble). `fgets` is a better choice for line input.

Comment: You have went way over the top! Thank you a million times! I got it to work so far. So the 'scanf ("%24[^\n]%*c", str)' scans the word entered then skips the line, and then the *c erases that line skip after it's used?

Comment: Yes. You see `%s` stops as the first whitespace (`space`), so using the character class `[^\n]` it reads everything up to the `'\n'`, (allowing a string like `"one two"`) then `%*c` read and discards the `'\n'`. The `*` is the *assignment suppression* operator for the `scanX` family of functions. It is used again with `%c%*c` to read `1-char` and then read/discard the `'\n'`.

Comment: Note, I made the following changes to the validation test `if (c < 'A' || ('Z' < c && c < 'a') || 'z' < c)` (which I had `&&` where `||` was needed). I had started to do the reverse of the test and left the original comparisons... Happens `:)`

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with your code, but I will address only the actual question you posed.

When you have a function which creates a result value to be used somewhere else, you need to return that value when the function ends.  The 'return' keyword will do this, but you must bear in mind that the thing being returned must continue to exist after the function has ended (as noted by @David C. Rankin in the comments).

Locally declared variables will cease to exist when the function ends, so the solution is to declare them in a wider scope.

```
// declare the string in a wider scope
// provide one extra character space for the string terminator \0 character
char inputStr[25 + 1];
// pass the string to the function which will fill it with the entered string
// NOTE: to avoid risk of someone entering too many letters in the string, we
// also pass in the length of the string buffer
enterWord(inputStr, 25);
```

The changes to the enterWord function would be:

```
void enterWord(char* str, int length){
    printf("Please enter a single word that is no more than %d characters: ", length);
    // this should verify the length of the entered text to make sure it isn't too long... but that's not your question
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("\nThanks! You entered:  %s", str);
}
```

In the scope where you declared inputStr, the string will now contain the data entered by the user.

In this case we are returning the string from the function by a different mechanism than the 'return' keyword.  Here we are passing a pointer to the first letter of the buffer space, so that the function will fill the original inputStr buffer from inside the function.

If you must use a more 'functional' coding paradigm, you might want to consider allocating space for the buffer on the heap using 'malloc', you would then need to remember to use 'free' at a later point in the code to release that allocated memory and avoid a memory leak, which is why that would not be my preferred solution in this case.